# what is difference between *[] *types.a and [] *types.b in golang

Tags: go

while looking into code I found below function declaration

```
func (c *Congress) Finalize(chain consensus.ChainHeaderReader, header *types.Header, state *state.StateDB, txs *[]*types.Transaction, uncles []*types.Header, receipts *[]*types.Receipt, systemTxs []*types.Transaction) error {
```

where two parameters are `txs *[]*types.Transaction, uncles []*types.Header,` what does it mean in terms of golang

just want to understand golang terminology with reference to above code

Comment: [Tour of Go: Pointers](https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/1)

Comment: Hmm, asking "I saw so-and-so and can someone explain it to me" is fine if you've done a bit of investigation yourself, but when you're asking for something that would be explained in an introductory tutorial it's a bit frustrating because you're asking other people to do the work for you. The tour of go is a good place to start, as suggested by JimB above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uncles []*types.Header

uncles is slice. If you copy it somewhere (perhaps by passing it in as a function parameter) updates to it will not propagate backwards to the original (with the nuance that changes to *elements* will propagate, but the size/data pointer of the original will remain unchanged).

txs *[]*types.Transaction

txs is a pointer to a slice. It’s sort of like a “reference” in that updates to the slice pointed at propagate to anyone else pointing to that slice.  So if you pass a *pointer* to a slice as a function parameter, the function may change the properties of the slice pointed to (adding/removing elements).